# Why doesnt my top and bottom physics body resize for the iPad?

Tags: ios, swift, skphysicsbody

I have a physicsBody for the bottom of my screen and for the top. It fits perfectly for my iPhone but when i go to the iPad simulator its a couple inches away from the top of the screen and bottom of the screen. It doesnt fit on the edge of the screens for the iPad for some reason. Can someone help me with this? Thanks! Heres the code im using:

```
let wall1 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.clearColor(), size: CGSize(width: 2000, height: 5))
let wall2 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.clearColor(), size: CGSize(width: 2000, height: 5))


   func wall() {


    //top wall border
    wall1.position  = CGPointMake(self.frame.width / 2, self.size.height / 1.1)
    wall1.physicsBody  = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: wall1.size)
    wall1.physicsBody!.dynamic  = false
    wall1.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask  = SideBlockCategory
    wall1.physicsBody!.restitution = 0
    wall1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = HeroCategory
    wall1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    wall1.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true


    //bottom wall border
    wall2.position  = CGPointMake(self.frame.width / 2, self.size.height / 8.0)
    wall2.physicsBody  = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: wall2.size)
    wall2.physicsBody!.dynamic  = false
    wall2.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask  = SideBlockCategory
    wall2.physicsBody!.restitution = 0
    wall2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = HeroCategory
    wall2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    wall2.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
//top wall border
wall1.position  = CGPointMake(self.frame.width / 2, self.frame.height - 2.5)

//bottom wall border 
wall2.position  = CGPointMake(self.frame.width / 2, 2.5)
```

Comment: This works for the iPad now but for the iPhone the border goes a little out of the screen instead of lining up with the edge of the screen.

Comment: log self.frame.height or self.frame.height to see if your are getting correct resolution.